# Automatically get info for ::before element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I've been trying to figure out a wait to get this to work with having multiple tables on a single web page.

```
<table class="table table-striped basic">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Saturday</th>
            <th class="time">10:30am</th>
            <th class="time">11:00am</th>
            <th class="time">11:30am</th>
            <th class="time">12:00pm</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>3/5/2016</td>
            <td>15231</td>
            <td>15232</td>
            <td>15233</td>
            <td>15234</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3/5/2016</td>
            <td>15231</td>
            <td>15232</td>
            <td>15233</td>
            <td>15234</td>
        </tr>
```

```
<script>
    var time = $('.time').text();
    $(function() {
        $('table td:nth-child(2)').attr('data-before-content', time);
        $('table td:nth-child(3)').attr('data-before-content', time);
        $('table td:nth-child(4)').attr('data-before-content', time);
        $('table td:nth-child(5)').attr('data-before-content', time);
    });

</script>
```

CSS:

```
 .table td:nth-child(2)::before {
    content: attr(data-before-content);
}
```

Trying to figure out a way to get the context of each "th" and place it ::before in the CSS while having multiple tables. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you thinking something along the lines of this?  You can use a combination of `.each()`, `.eq()`, and `.not()`

```js
$('table tr').each(function(){
  $('td', this).not(':first-child').each(function(i){
    $(this).attr('data-before-content', $('.time').eq(i).text());  
  });
});
```

```css
.table td:before {
  content: attr(data-before-content) '\00a0';
}

.table td {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped basic">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Saturday</th>
      <th class="time">10:30am</th>
      <th class="time">11:00am</th>
      <th class="time">11:30am</th>
      <th class="time">12:00pm</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>3/5/2016</td>
      <td>15231</td>
      <td>15232</td>
      <td>15233</td>
      <td>15234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3/5/2016</td>
      <td>15231</td>
      <td>15232</td>
      <td>15233</td>
      <td>15234</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In case the `.time` data is table specific (which is more likely the case I would think), I'd recommend using this instead:

```js
$('table tr').each(function(){
  var $t = $(this).closest('table').find('.time');
  $('td', this).not(':first-child').each(function(i){
    $(this).attr('data-before-content', $t.eq(i).text());  
  });
});
```

```css
.table td:before {
  content: attr(data-before-content) '\00a0';
}

.table td {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped basic">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Saturday</th>
      <th class="time">10:30am</th>
      <th class="time">11:00am</th>
      <th class="time">11:30am</th>
      <th class="time">12:00pm</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>3/5/2016</td>
      <td>15231</td>
      <td>15232</td>
      <td>15233</td>
      <td>15234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3/5/2016</td>
      <td>15231</td>
      <td>15232</td>
      <td>15233</td>
      <td>15234</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<table class="table table-striped basic">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Monday</th>
      <th class="time">7:30pm</th>
      <th class="time">9:00pm</th>
      <th class="time">10:30pm</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>3/7/2016</td>
      <td>15231</td>
      <td>15232</td>
      <td>15233</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3/7/2016</td>
      <td>15231</td>
      <td>15232</td>
      <td>15233</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This seems to be working, Ill have to test it out with having two tables on the same page with different info. Thanks, this at least gives me a starting point.

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad I could help.  Just curious, but do both tables have different "time" data?

Comment: yes they do, that's where the problem is happening, but it can be changed easily unless you have any suggestions.

Comment: @DanielRubio I've updated my answer.  To clarify, I've added the use of `.closest()` which searches up the DOM tree until it finds a match.  In this case it's searching for the closest table ancestor node and then `.time` below that.

Answer (score 0):

`var time = $('.time');` returns an all the text of all element with the class `.time`. Instead, you should use something like `$('.time:nth-child('+i+')').text()` inside a for-loop.

```
<script>
    var time = $('.time');
    $(function() {
      for(var i = 0, len=time.length; i<len; i++){
        $('table td:nth-child(' +i+ ')').attr('data-before-content', $(time[i]).text());
      }
    });

</script>
```